# How to power down on signal from Tripp Lite UPS?

Tags: ups

After experiencing boot problems after power failure, I want to make sure that I do everything I can to prevent this from happening again.
Is there software/driver to gracefully power down Ubuntu when a USB-connected Tripp Lite UPS signals power loss?

Comment: It is built in to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look at the `nut`(Network UPS Tools) package.

The driver for your device is most likely `tripplite_usb`.